# Malformed date field to populate into new field in elasticsearch

Tags: date, elasticsearch, malformed

I have created a index in elasticsearch with multiple date field and formatted  the column as `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss`. Eventually I found the date is malformed and was populating wrong data into the fields. The index has more than 600 000 records and I don't want to leave any data. Now I need to create another field or new index with same date field and format as `YYYY-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z` and need to populate all the records into new index or new fields.

I have used the date processor pipeline as below. but it fails. Correct me anything wrong here.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/date-malform
{
  "description": "convert malformed date to timestamp",
    "processors": [      
      {
        "date": {
          "field": "event_tm",
          "target_field" : "event_tm",
          "formats" : ["YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.Z"]
          "timezone" : "UTC"
        }
      },      
      {
        "date": {
          "field": "vendor_start_dt",
          "target_field" : "vendor_start_dt",
          "formats" : ["YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.Z"]
          "timezone" : "UTC"
        }
      },
        {
        "date": {
          "field": "vendor_end_dt",
          "target_field" : "vendor_end_dt",
          "formats" : ["YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.Z"]
          "timezone" : "UTC"
        }
      }   
    ]
}
```

I have created the pipeline and used reindex as below

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "index": "tog_gen_test"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "data_mv",
    "pipeline": "some_ingest_pipeline",
    "version_type": "external"
  }
}
```

I am getting the below error while running the reindex

```
"failures": [
    {
      "index": "data_mv",
      "type": "_doc",
      "id": "rwN64WgB936y_JOyjc57",
      "cause": {
        "type": "exception",
        "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to parse date [2019-02-12 10:29:35]",
        "caused_by": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unable to parse date [2019-02-12 10:29:35]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
            "reason": "unable to parse date [2019-02-12 10:29:35]",
            "caused_by": {
              "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
              "reason": "Illegal pattern component: T"
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use logstash like Shailesh Pratapwar suggested, but you also have the option to use elasticsearch reindex + ingest to do the same:

1. Create an ingest pipeline with the proper date processor in order to fix the date format/manipulation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/date-processor.html
2. reindex the data from the old index, to a new index, with the date manipulation. from: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html

> Reindex can also use the Ingest Node feature by specifying a pipeline

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188392/discussion-on-answer-by-ziv-malformed-date-field-to-populate-into-new-field-in-e). Please remember to update the answer with any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Logstash**.

[Read from ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) using LogStash.

[Manipulate the date format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-action).

[Write to ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) using LogStash.

Comment: Yes.. I thought to use the same Logstash. But I need to know how to handle the data date field that are malformed. 
for ex: a field event_date is in the format of  "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss" and I need to populate this data into new field with date datatype ( format as "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.Z"). So could you please help me to get the conversion level and populate the data.

Comment: Apparently, if i could exclude the "HH:mm:ss" from the data in the old field and I think ES could understand the date format as normal and load the data into new field or new index with the modified field.

for ex:
`2019-02-03 00:00:00 to 2019-02-03 ` this conversion could help to insert the old data

Comment: Yes. ES accepts ISO date formats in which time is an optional part.